Zoom and Marketing cloud Integration not working
We exclusively rely on a Webhook-only application to capture Webinar Registrations data.It was working smoothly. However, we’ve observed a sudden halt in data transmission to our Marketing Cloud data extension. No modifications were made on our end within the Marketing Cloud platform.
Deployment : 2023-10-10 . No data coming since : 2023-11-05
In an attempt to troubleshoot, we re-validated the endpoint, only to encounter an ‘Please validate your endpoint URL’ error message.Zoom support team indicated a potential issue with the hash value, but it puzzles us why this discrepancy arose now when the system operated flawlessly last year.
Interestingly, we noticed two records were captured in the Marketing Cloud data extension recently, but upon personal testing, the system remains unresponsive.
Are there any recent updates pertaining to hash response mechanisms, particularly HMAC-SHA, that could shed light on this issue?

As SFMC does not provide webhooks OOTB, I am assuming you are using a code resource or similar, to provide webhook URL to Zoom. Did you try calling this URL from Postman or similar?

Hi @LukasLunow
Yes, we are using a code resource. We conducted testing with our cloud page, and it yielded the expected format result. However, it fails to function properly with the actual registrant data.

Yes you are correct, there has been an additional "HMAC SHA-256 hash" required now to authenticate webhooks after OCT 2023.

Validate your webhook endpoint using HMAC SHA-256 hash
As there is NO OOB solution, I have tried one of the alternate method, please refer this LinkeinArticle

Could you please provide the link? I'm unable to access it.
Could you please share the link again? It's not accessible.
Are you referring to this article? It seems the external app will cost $5 per month. Do we have any other way to achieve this integration?
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sfmc-ninja?trackingId=nvCZNjYVTFOFWRq%2BmA4PSA%3D%3D&lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_detail_base%3BezDRI53AQ928jhqNoFuU%2Bw%3D%3D

Try this link https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sfmc-ninja ... yes Heroku needs atleast $5 license now

Thank you for providing the article. Do we need to purchase the basic package for Heroku? I am reviewing this to understand how many API calls will be made from Zoom so that we can purchase accordingly. Are there any specific details you would like to highlight for this solution?

Thank you for providing the article. Do we need to purchase the basic package for Heroku? I am reviewing this to understand how many API calls will be made from Zoom so that we can purchase accordingly. Are there any specific details you would like to highlight for this solution?

Sorry I do not have these details, I recommend to a check with Heroku support team.
